# How to get message payload on @SqsListener exception handling

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, amazon-sqs

I have a scenario where I want send notification in case of validation failure

```
  public void onMessage(@Valid @Payload String jsonPayload,
                        @Headers Map<String, String> headersMap){
try{

//do something

} catch (Exception e){
//send notification using message content and exception message
}}
```

catch block is never executed. Any suggestion on this please.
springboot version:3.1.1
springcloud version:3.0.1
aws java sdk version: 2.20.97

Comment: Please edit your question to replace `//do something` with the code that you're expecting to throw an exception, otherwise we won't be able to tell why it's not throwing one.